# Working With Stacked UIButtons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, touch-event

Hey guys, so I have this search bar in my view along with many buttons below it. So when the search bar is tapped, a keyboard pops up, however I want the user to be able to click anywhere below the search bar and above the keyboard to get out of searching mode. I have been scavenging SO for a bit and came across a solution that suggested that I create an invisible button which intercepts touch events which I can use to resign first responder status from the search bar. And I can merely hide/disable the button when I do not need it so that the buttons below it may be tapped right? Wrong. `setHidden` nor `setEnabled:` aren't doing the trick. Here is the relevant code:

```
//touch event on button outsideSearchBarButton which is invisible
- (IBAction)selectOutsideSearchBar:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Selected outside search bar");
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [outsideSearchBarButton setEnabled:NO];
    [outsideSearchBarButton setHidden:YES];
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)aSearchBar {
    NSLog(@"searchbarTextDidBeginEditing");
    [outsideSearchBarButton setHidden:NO];
    [outsideSearchBarButton setEnabled:YES];
}
```

Setting the button to disabled or hidden via nib file does not help me at all. Either the button never exists (I can't click between search bar and keyboard and have keyboard go away) or always exists (I can't click any of the buttons below this invisible button). Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//touch event on button outsideSearchBarButton which is invisible
- (IBAction)selectOutsideSearchBar:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Selected outside search bar");
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    outsideSearchBarButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)aSearchBar {
    NSLog(@"searchbarTextDidBeginEditing");
    outsideSearchBarButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
```

Do this.

Comment: Yeah this did the trick, apparently my old code worked as well... I realized I stupidly did not connect my invisible button to the IBOutlet variable outsideSearchBarButton, thus that code that was modifying the button wasn't doing anything. So my old code did in fact work, however I feel this is a much more elegant solution, that is why I am marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

go to the interface builder and select the button on which you are removing the keyboard during search, then select  layout from the above menu and select send to back.Then in the inspector window set the button style to custom.

Hope this helps you.......

Comment: + rep for describing that I had to select button style custom, I already knew that but I think this can be useful to others.